# Flutter does not connect to the server on some devices In Release Mode

Tags: java, android, flutter, api, dart

I published the app and I encounter an error on some devices (Android)

On some devices, the app does not connect to the web service (API) to send or receive information This problem occurs in the Android version

I also put the Android Permission in AndroidManifest But it does not work

One of the devices : Samsung Galaxy A10 | Android 8

This device has this version installed : `v7a`

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="test"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <activity
      android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
   
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        
        <meta-data
          android:name= "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        

        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
          <data android:scheme="test" android:host="transaction-ok" />
          <data android:scheme="test" android:host="transaction-faild" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

networkSecurityConfig : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZGdL.png

and my code :

```
static Future loginCode(String phone) async {

    String url = 'https://panel.test.ir/api/v1/login_code/lawyer';

    try{
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: {
          "mobile_number": phone
        },
        headers: {
          accept : acceptValue
        }
      ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
      print(response.statusCode);

      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      try{
        showToast(data['message']);
      }catch(e){}

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
    
        if(data['new_user'] == null){
          return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
  
      }else{
        showError(response);
        return null;
      }
    }catch(e){
      showToast("Send Data Error");
      return null;
    }
}
```

And after 30 seconds, the request will be canceled automatically

android -> app -> BG: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWMMh.png)